# Does the following two code get the same result?

Tags: java, concurrency

below are two code snippet, one is sequential, the other is parallel:

```
public<T> void sequentialRecursive(List<Node<T>> nodes, Collection<T> results)
{
    for(Node<T> n: nodes) {
    results.add(n.compute());
    sequentialRecursive(n.getChildren(), results);
    }
}

public<T> void parallelRecursive(final Executor exec, List<Node<T>> nodes, final Collection<T> results) {
    for(final Node<T> n : nodes){
    exec.execute(new Runnable(){
    public void run()
    {
     results.add(n.compute());
     }
    });
  parallelRecursive(exec, n.getChildren(), results);
 }
}
```

I want to know if the above two functions generate the same results? Is below results possible?
results of SequentialRecursive is: [1,2,3,4,5] and the result of ParallelRecursive is:[1,3,2,5,4].

Comment: Did you try actually running it ? :)

Comment: What is the output when you tried to execute both methods?

Comment: Sorry I did not try it out, it is an example in a book. I feel confused about it.

Comment: What I can tell is -the second one is very *inefficient*.

Comment: maybe the compute function will take a long time, at least the second one is parallel.

Comment: And what would be the point of *parallelism* if it doesn't bring *efficiency* ?

Comment: why it's not efficient? @TheLostMind

Comment: @Charlesjean -  The first one runs everything in one thread so less (very little overhead of context switching). The second one executes a new thread each time the method is recursively called. What do you think - `exec.execute(new Runnable()` does?

Comment: @TheLostMind how do you know context switching is more expensive than n.compute()? What about the host has many cpu?

Comment: After all I just want to know if these two functions can get the same result ...

Answer (score 1):

The second function is going to get results in an unpredictable order, because it's creating tasks that each go and calculate an answer for a node, and the executor processes those tasks by giving them to different threads. There is no telling what order the results will be added in, it depends on which thread gets picked by the scheduler when.

One way to reliably get the same results for both of these would be to use a SingleThreadExecutor for the second example.